Which situations will cause a segmentation fault using the "strlcpy" function? And under what scenarios will the "strlcpy" function return (NULL)?
I want to create a function like strlcpy, and this is the code:
size_t  ft_strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t dstsize)
{
    size_t  src_len;
    size_t  j;

    src_len = ft_strlen(src);
    if (dstsize == 0)
        return (src_len);
    j = 0;
    while (src[j] && j < dstsize - 1)
    {
        dst[j] = src[j];
        j++;
    }
    dst[j] = '\0';
    return (src_len);
}

This is my main() function:
int main()
{
    char dst[20];
    const char *src = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    int d = ft_strlcpy(dst, src, len);
    printf("%s\n", dst);
    printf("%d\n", d);
}

In my main() function, I want to check if the src is NULL, but i can't use strlcpy, i wanna just ask u if it should be a seg fault or it will return (NULL).

The answer depends on implementation of ft_strlen(src): What does it  if src==NULL? And then it depends how do you check the result.

strlcpy will crash if you pass NULL as src buffer pointer. Why do you even try?

Returning NULL is not an option for a function with that signature.  Undefined behavior is an option, and the program crashing with a segfault is one possible manifestation, but C does not define anything you can do to guarantee a segfault specifically.

I think the title question misses the point, though.  If you want a string copying function whose behavior you like better than strcpy()'s then choose the behavior you want, and implement that.  I don't see why you feel bound to reproduce the behavior of strlcpy() in full detail.

One problem with strlcpy is that it always finds the length of src, so fails if you pass an unterminated value.

@JohnBollinger It's homework. The 42 C programming course, as far as I can tell, expects students to write their own version of the standard(ish) library.

It has some telltales of homework, @Shawn, but if an assignment requires specifically reimplementing non-standard strlcpy() then the course materials and / or instructor would be the appropriate source for details of the behavior required of the replica.  On the other hand, the OP should distinguish between reimplementing the function because they are specifically tasked to do so and reimplementing it because they want similar functionality but are forbidden to call library functions.  The latter case does not necessitate perfectly matching all details of the model function.

@K,  Post the function definition of ft_strlen() to get good answers.

"n my main() function, I want to check if the src is NULL" - I mean, you don't have to check. You know it's null because you made it null yourself! const char *src = NULL;


under what scenarios will the "strlcpy" function return (NULL)?

At least this one:
NULL is the null pointer constant (a pointer or some integer) and strlcpy() returns a size_t.
It is strange to compare NULL to a size_t.
When src[0] == 0, then src_len is expected to be 0.  If dst_size is also zero, then the function returns 0.
Then this size_t value of 0 could equate to NULL.


I want to check if the src is NULL, but i can't use strlcpy, ...

To check is src is NULL, use direct code.  No need to call strlcpy().
if (src == NULL)

